# How to convert a UTC timestamp to a time zone, would you set to the time zone in 'fromISO' or do you prefer 'setZone', or does it matter?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, timezone, utc, luxon

What is the best way to convert a UTC timestamp to a specific time zone using Luxon?

I have a UTC timestamp "YYYY-DD-MMTHH:MM:SSZ"

I've found two ways to convert the UTC timestamp to a time zone; either by specifying the time zone in 'fromISO' or using 'setZone':

```
const luxonUrl  = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.3/luxon.min.js';
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(luxonUrl).getContentText());

function utctotimezone() {
  const timeZ     = '2022-06-01T20:00:00Z';
  const utctime   = 'UTC';
  const uktime    = 'Europe/London';
  const zISO      = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(timeZ).toISO({suppressMilliseconds: true});
  const utcISO    = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(timeZ, {zone: utctime}).toISO({suppressMilliseconds: true});
  const ukISO     = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(timeZ, {zone: uktime}).toISO({suppressMilliseconds: true});
  const ukzoneutc = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(timeZ, {zone: utctime}).setZone(uktime).toISO({suppressMilliseconds: true});
  console.log(utcISO,' - utcISO\n'+zISO,' - zISO\n'+ukISO,' - ukISO\n'+ukzoneutc,' - uk zone from utc');
}
```

So to convert a UTC timestamp to a time zone, would you set to the time zone in 'fromISO' or do you prefer 'setZone', or does it matter?

references:

- https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting
- https://moment.github.io/luxon/demo/global.html
- https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/docs/zones.md
- https://www.thisdot.co/blog/how-to-handle-time-zones-using-datetime-and-luxon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.fromISO()`, setting the { zone } parameter to the desired value or use the `setZone()` method.

We can see they will result in the same value using the `.equals()` method (Two DateTimes are equal if they represent the same millisecond, have the same zone and location, and are both valid)

It then depends on which approach you prefer personally.

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

const zone = 'Europe/London';
const timeZ = '2022-06-01T20:00:00Z';
const dateTime1 = DateTime.fromISO(timeZ, { zone });
const dateTime2 = DateTime.fromISO(timeZ).setZone(zone);

console.log('dateTime1:', dateTime1.toISO({suppressMilliseconds: true}))
console.log('dateTime2:', dateTime2.toISO({suppressMilliseconds: true}))

console.log('Times are equal:', dateTime1.equals(dateTime2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-6ZJuab/UnRq1muTChgrVxJhSgygmL2GMLVmSJN7pcBEqJ1dWPbqN9CiZ6U3HrcApTIJsLnMgXYBYgtVkJ8fWiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```